# Big O and little o, absolute convergence of series where $a_n = O(b_n) $ or $a_n = o(b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

Big O and little o, absolute convergence of series where $a_n = O(b_n) $ or $a_n = o(b_n)$

Prove
If $\sum_n b_n$ converges absolutely then $\sum_n a_n$ converges absolutely

BWO Contrapositive (BigO):

assume $\sum_n \left|a_n\right|$ doesn't converge and $a_n = O(b_n)$

Find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $M > 0$ s.t. $\forall n \ge N$, $\left|a_n\right| \le M\left|b_n\right|$ then $\displaystyle \frac{\left|a_n\right|}{M} \le \left|b_n\right|$ and since $\sum_n \left|a_n\right|$ then $\sum_n \frac{\left|a_n\right|}{M} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_n \left|a_n\right| $ does not converge and $\frac{1}{M}\sum_n \left|a_n\right| \le \sum_n \left|b_n\right| $ doesn't converge

For little o

Let $a_n = o(b_n)$ and assume $\sum_n \left|b_n\right|$ converges,

let $\epsilon >0$ find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n \ge N$, $\left|a_n\right| \le \epsilon\left|b_n\right| \implies \displaystyle \frac{\left|a_n\right|}{\left|b_n\right|} \le \epsilon$ hence the fraction is bounded  and $\left|b_n\right| \to 0$ from the assm. above. I think I can conclude from here that $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left|a_n\right|}{\left|b_n\right|} = c \le \epsilon, 0<c<\infty$ so $\sum_n\left|a_n\right|$ convergences be the limit comparison test

Comment: I am not sure why you do this  twice. If it is a little o it is a big O. Thus doing the first suffices. Personally I would not prove the first part by contradiction but it works.

Comment: Why do we have $\lim_n \frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|} = c$ for some $ 0<c<\epsilon$ given that $a_n = o(b_n)$? Are you trying to argue by contradiction?

Comment: @Xiao because I'm trying to use the Limit Comparison Test to achieve the desired result

Comment: @oliverjones then what is your definition for $a_n = o(b_n)$? Doesn't this imply $\lim_n \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$? given $b_n$ are positive

Comment: @Xiao $a_n = o(b_n)$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in  \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for $n \ge N$, $\left| a_n \right| \le \epsilon \left|b_n\right|$ I was trying to do the Big O proof my contrapostive. and Direct for little o

Comment: @oliverjones then $a_n = o(b_n)$ contradicts with $\lim_n \frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|} = c$ for some $c>0$, right?

Comment: @Xiao why does it contradict it? I'm not trying to prove it by contradiction.

Comment: @oliverjones Take $\epsilon = \frac{c}{2}$, then from $a_n = o(b_n)$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $$|a_n|\leq \frac{c}{2} |b_n|$$ then for $b_n\neq 0$ this is $$\frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|} \leq \frac{c}{2} \quad \quad \forall n\geq N.$$

Comment: @Xiao I see now, I'll have to do it differently then cause I wasn't doing it by contradiction